# Responsive Layout with DIVS + Image Positioning

Tags: html, css, layout

This is the layout I am trying to achieve: [image: Desired Layout]

Here is my current HTML + CSS (I'm just learning so sorry if it's repetitive and off :))

```
<div class="collection clearfix">
    <div class="image-left1"> </div>
    <div class="icon-left1">
        <img src="images/mainLP-chair-icon.png" alt="Chair Collection">
        <p>Chair Collection</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collection clearfix">
    <div class="icon-right1">
        <img src="images/mainLP-lamp-icon.png" height="48" width="34" alt="Lamp Collection">
        <p>Lamp Collection</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-right1"> </div>
</div>
```

... it alternates for a total of 5 divs stacked.

and CSS is:

```
/* =================== Main Section =================== */

.collection {
    padding-top: 25px;
}

/*=================== CHAIRS ===================*/

.image-left1 {
    background: url(../images/mainLP-chairs.jpg) center;
    height: 570px;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon-left1 {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #c7db9c;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 25px solid white;
    height: 570px;
}


.icon-left1 p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
    left: 36px;

}

.icon-left1 img {
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 222px;
    left: 76px;
}

/*=================== LAMPS ===================*/

.image-right1 {
    background: url(../images/mainLP-lamps.jpg) center;
    height: 570px;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}


.icon-right1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #f4dc86;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 25px solid white;
    height: 570px;
}


.icon-right1 p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
    left: 36px;
}

.icon-right1 img {
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 222px;
    left: 93px;
}


.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}  (This is around everything)
```

I'm not concerned yet about responsive but I should be down the road. A few issues I'm seeing.

The background image for each of the containers isn't sizing properly - it's getting cut off. How would I fix that?

There must be a better way to float the icon and text in the div beside the image../ right now it's wonky and positioned relative which I don't think is correct. OR if it is correct I think I have coded it wrong.

Comment: can you use `background-size:cover` on image background

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's getting cut off"? Is it not expanding to fit the width? or is it growing too much and some parts are hidden? How is it failing?

Comment: If your images are proportional in size to your divs, then you can use background-size:100% 100%; - regarding the other questions, I didn't quite understand them sorry. Best of luck.

Comment: "Down the road" is the wrong time to think about a responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this, the solution is simple, just add:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Make code makes all elements include padding and the border in their width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    /* =================== Main Section =================== */

    .collection {
        padding-top: 25px;
    }

    /*=================== CHAIRS ===================*/

    .image-left1 {
        background: url(http://hbu.h-cdn.co/assets/15/36/980x654/gallery-1441147503-green-hills-residence-5.jpg) center;
        height: 570px;
        width: 70%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .icon-left1 {
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        background-color: #c7db9c;
        padding: 10px;
        border-left: 25px solid white;
        height: 570px;
    }


    .icon-left1 p {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        top: 220px;
        left: 36px;

    }

    .icon-left1 img {
        border: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 222px;
        left: 76px;
    }

    /*=================== LAMPS ===================*/

    .image-right1 {
        background: url(http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/creative-lamps-chandeliers-16-2.jpg) center;
        height: 570px;
        width: 70%;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .icon-right1 {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
        background-color: #f4dc86;
        padding: 10px;
        border-right: 25px solid white;
        height: 570px;
    }


    .icon-right1 p {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        top: 220px;
        left: 36px;

    }

    .icon-right1 img {
        border: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 222px;
        left: 93px;
    }


    .wrapper {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="collection clearfix">
    <div class="image-left1"> </div>
    <div class="icon-left1">
        <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="Chair Collection">
        <p>Chair Collection</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collection clearfix">
    <div class="icon-right1">
        <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height="48" width="34" alt="Lamp Collection">
        <p>Lamp Collection</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-right1"> </div>
</div>
```

Regarding the background being cut off, make try using `background-size:contain`...as `background-size: cover` is not working for you. You normally use `background: ... no-repeat` with `background-size:contain`.